# Confirm and/or undo job application

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I accidentally sent a job application that I was working on and was devastated to learn that there is no "safety mechanism" in place to prevent this kind of thing from happening.

I will now have to send a separate email to the employer to amend the accidentally sent application. Job applications are critical enough that some kind of safety mechanism should exist to avoid accidents like this.

Two suggestions:

- A confirmation step where the user has to tick a box or something like that before the application is sent. Something like: "You are about to apply for position X at company Y. Are you sure?"
- An "undo" button that gives the user 30 seconds or so to undo sending the application.

Comment: Oh gosh. Things like this is *why* I have Undo Send turned on in Gmail.

Comment: Thought you were being sarcastic and aaalmost didn't look it up but it turns out [there is indeed an Undo Send in GMail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2819488?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that :( Agree that this feature would be helpful - personally, Gmail's Undo Send has saved me a few times. We don't have immediate plans to work on this, but will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have just shipped this!

Once you apply, you're shown a toast with an Undo link that you can use to... well, undo your application :)

[image]

You have up to 30 seconds to change your mind.

Comment: But how can we cancel our application if we change our minds two days later?

Comment: two days later, we've already sent your information to the company (either by email or to their ATS). If you want to cancel your application, you should say that to the company directly at that point.

Comment: After Undo is clicked, the application SEEMS to remain in sent state AND also cannot be re-sent later (which is even worse scenario in case the application is actually undone, despite seemingly remaining sent, but cannot be resent). Very confusing!

Comment: please create a new question explaining the behavior you're seeing so that the team can look into it

Comment: I recommend using another color to be more noticed [ Gmail Example ]