# How to "undo" the submittal of an application

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

How do I undo submitting an application for a job on SO?
When you apply for a job and "Submit" and it says "Awesome..." it should have a link to "undo" as people can mistakenly apply or apply and then realize after reading more about the job they may want to cancel out of it.

Also the email that is sent could include a link that says "Didn't mean to apply to this job?  Click here to cancel..."

Feature-request: Allow me to manage my applications.

Comment: Even if it's decided a full-on ability to manage applications is too much (as you'd have to implement an UI, set up limits for abuse, etc. etc.) it seems fair to allow for something like a 5-minute undo window at least. Or until the employer has seen the application - although that would allow you to see when the employer has read it which is not great.

Comment: Lots of employers rely on emails to "see" the applications... so telling when they've seen it may not be really possible. I agree that undo would make a whole lot of sense, and that the ability to manage applications is something we should work on. Even if we have to show employers a "this candidate withdrawn their application" message. That's still better than reaching out to the candidate only to learn they didn't want to apply after all.

Comment: I don't mind a grace period of ten minutes.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. As [Donna mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350485/confirm-and-or-undo-job-application#comment513164_350485) it's something we're thinking about.