# Express interest Button and application

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

A couple days ago I found a job opportunity I am interested in so, I clicked "Express Interest".

I was attempting to formally apply today. I clicked "Apply now" button and wrote down a cover letter. I then Clicked "Apply" and a notification appeared on top of page stating that the application had been sent to the company.

The problem is that I didn't received any confirmation, and worse, looking into my profile's "Sent Messages" I can see the "Express Interest" from two days ago but not the today's application.

Any clue?

Comment: Somewhat related I raised a feature request not long ago asking for something simmilar to what we have for `all actions` with questions, the interface for what you as a user, have actually done should be made simpler so we can follow along our application properly and with greater clarity for what has happened.

Comment: Looking into this now, thanks for reporting!

Comment: @lix could you share a link to your feature request?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371025/make-jobs-ask-a-question-history-available-on-my-profiles-actions-tab @max

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you very much for reporting this.

I can confirm that unfortunately, you're right. You applied for a job, we showed you a success message but didn't do anything with the data you sent.

This was a bug I introduced when adding the [undo applications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371460/920295) feature. We use feature flags extensively (that we set to `true` in dev but to `false` in prod when we're testing a feature) and I didn't feature flag one of the changes I did.

We try to merge everything to `master` as soon as possible (and avoid stale branches), so between the moment that I merged it and when it was actually tested, 10 days passed. And when another dev tested it, she discovered the bug that prevented applications from working *if the user had previously expressed interest*. I fixed it and shipped undo applications.

What we failed to recognize is that this bug affected applications submitted between `2018-07-13 15:17` and `2018-07-23 20:08` *if the user had already expressed interest on the job* even when the feature flag was off. As you applied in that range, your application wasn't properly processed.

This was made worse by the fact that, as we were treating this applications as duplicates, we were showing a success message... so it was really hard for a user to tell that there was anything wrong. Thankfully, you went ahead and checked on your sent applications.

We have identified the affected users and we are in the process of sending emails clearly outlining the applications that weren't processed with links to the job listings so that they can apply again. I'm also going to tweak that success toast so that it only shows a success if it's a duplicate of an application posted in the last minute.

Thanks for bringing this up to our attention... if you want to apply to that job, you should be able to do it now.