# Where is the "Undo" function for "Express interest"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've checked some jobs on Stack Overflow where I pressed the "Express interest" button. There was an popup where it was possible to undo that action.

So how it is possible after the popup isn't visible anymore to undo that?

I've already made some researches but I haven't found a solution. I've just found out where I find the messages area for jobs.

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Comment: yesterday *somebody* shipped [undo for applications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371460/920295). It's very likely that that somebody broke undo express interest. That somebody is currently looking into it.

Comment: I've just expressed interest into a job and was able to undo it. Do you have any errors on your console?

Comment: No, there was no error. One problem, however, seems to be that if I undo an "express interest" this will not be reflected correctly. I have just tested this and still get the message that I still share my interest but I can still see the "Express Interest" button and im able to click it.

Comment: I was able to undo that and got the success message. I've added 2 screenshots. I thought that's why it would seem like I would show interest but which I have undone. That's why I asked for another place where it is still possible except in the popup.

Comment: Thanks! alright, I see that you have 1 interest today that was not withdrawn and the one that's included in the screenshot that you successfully withdrew. So the error here is: We're showing the express interest indicator on withdrawn applications. I'll work on fixing it today. Thanks for your help figuring this one out!

Comment: Sounds good, I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were processing `Undo`s correctly, but we were still showing the indicator on the jobs where interest was withdrawn.

I've deployed a fix, so this should no longer be an issue.

Thanks again for helping us get this fixed!